# What's the package of a Java array class?

Tags: jvm, specifications

This question is for JVM specification advocates. According to the JVMS, Java SE 7 edition, section 5.3.3, last paragraph:

> If the component type is a reference type, the accessibility of the array class is determined by the accessibility of its component type. Otherwise, the accessibility of the array class is public.

Thus an array class can have package visibility. Logically I would expect that, if foo.baz.MyClass has package visibility, then an array of MyClass is visible only to package foo.baz. But I can't find anything in the specification supporting this view. Section 5.3 says that the run-time package, that should be used to determine visibility constraints, is built of the binary name of the package plus the defining classloader. But the binary name comes from the classfile, and array classes do not have classfiles. Similar issue for the primitive classes (e.g., Boolean.TYPE), which apparently have public visibility, but I cannot find information about them anywhere.

Can you spot a point in the JVMS where the package of array/primitive classes is clearly defined (or a reason why there is none)?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that exactly what the quote from the specification is saying?

> If the component type is a reference type, the accessibility of the array class is determined by the accessibility of its component type.

If you have a class some.pkg.SomeClass and want to use it as some.pkg.SomeClass[] the accessibility is determined by the accessibility of its component type. In this case the component type is some.pkg.SomeClass.

The other case is for native types, and you can't add more native types to Java.